# How to play a sound loop when an alert is displayed using UILocationNotification

Tags: audio, uilocalnotification

Sound only played once when an alert is displayed using UILocationNotification.How to play a sound loop when an alert is displayed in background like Clock.app.

Answer (score 2):

You can't play a sound loop when a UILocationNotification fires.   You get one sound to play, and that sound must be less than 30 seconds, or the system sound will play instead.  You can make the sound longer and repeat it yourself in audio editor, but this of course increases the size of the sound (and iOS doesn't yet support compressed formats like .mp3 as the sound file in UILocationNotification).